# How can I get customized value from Redis cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I am working on Redis with spring boot.
And I am new in Redis.
I am stuck in a problem where I need customized data from Redis cache.

For example, the key is 1 and the object stored in Redis is

```
{
    name,
    age,
    DOB,
    ...    
}
```

and I want to retrieve only 2 two of them from Redis e.g. name and age
But for a given key Redis returns the complete object.
But I need only custom fields from that object.

I have no idea how to get over this problem and I cannot do like just to cache only 2 required fields.
Caching of the complete object is required for other purposes.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the object be like this
{
"name" : "John Doe",
"age": 30,
.
:

}

Comment: @Ameen.M yes the object is of key-value pair type

Answer (score 0):

You can use **hmget** operation and specify fields what you need. Next example from [official documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hmget):

```
redis> HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET myhash field2 "World"
(integer) 1
redis> HMGET myhash field1 field2 nofield
1) "Hello"
2) "World"
3) (nil)
```

**Edited:**
If you prefer use [list](https://redis.io/commands/lrange) it may look like this:

```
RPUSH mylist "name"
(integer) 1
redis> RPUSH mylist "age"
(integer) 2
redis> RPUSH mylist "DOB"
(integer) 3
```

Then you can use

```
LRANGE mylist 0 1
1) "name"
2) "age"
```

But if you need associate key with value for one object more elegant will be Hashes data structure

Comment: It gives the error : "WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value" @Vlad

Comment: Example above for `Hashes` data structure.What structure did you use?   If it's a list you can do something like this `LRANGE mylist 0 1 ` This return first two valuse from list

Comment: I am using hmset for putting the values

````e.g. jedis.hmset(key, value);````

where value is a <String,String> Map

Comment: Error what your recieve apears when you try to get value from,for example, list but key have been created for another data structure. I can recomend to clear all you keys and then uses `Hashes` for this task

Comment: Can you help me with an example for the list type?

Comment: @SauravDudeja "WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value" is because you already stored a different type for the key you are trying. Try an  unused key to first "hset" the hash map datatype as stated in this answer.